# Zend Engine Outdated (how do i update it?)

Tags: php, opcache

After installing opcache (after reading it would increase performance), i get the message that Zend Engine API is outdated. But i don't know how to update it?
I've looked everywhere, with no success.
It's a Centos 6 server, with PHP 5.4.41.
Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: It might be worth including in your question the method by which you installed opcache. Also note that opcache is bundled with PHP 5.5+, and 5.4 is nearing end of life, so if upgrading to a more recent version of PHP is an option that might be the best solution for you.